# Javascript candlestick chart

Tags: javascript, html, candlestick-chart

I am trying to use google visualization.arrayToDataTable
in order to make a candlestick chart
and when loading the data i had a problem this is the syntax:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  [DATE[len],Number(LOW[len]),Number(OPEN[len]),Number(CLOSE[len]),Number(HIGH[le])]
```

I have arrays of all the needed items and every thing works fine.
the problem is I need to put them one by one in each "len" position I want in the array.

How can you loop through it?